# fixed height and width for responsive bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive carousel with pictures that are not similar in the width and height.
I want to have a fixed size for the carousel no mather what are the size of pictures.
Here is the example:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x150" style="width:100%">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="New york" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the problem here..? looks everything is fine.

Comment: @sanojlawrence when I use pictures with different height or width, the size of the carousel change with the pictures.

Comment: can you add those images, what is different height or width

Comment: added answer with different sized images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method to add different sized images, to view in fixed `height:500px`

```css
.carousel-inner .item{
height:500px;
background-size:cover;
background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/1024x700)  ">
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/100x100)  ">
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/1024x700)  ">
      </div>

      <div class="item" style="background-image: url(//placehold.it/200x200)  ">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you try to avoid in-line styles. How about you try and use:

```
.item img{
width: 100%;
}
```

For adding width to your images.

And maybe adding a

```
.carousel{
height: 60vh
}
```

To your carousel.